# Firebase CloudFirestore PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been using Firebase's Realtime Database for a long time and thinking to try out the new Database because it is scalable and more efficient in querying data but i have this message from my LogCat

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Even though i have user authentication logged in when writing the data i still get this message.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your RULES script?

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code and rules that reproduce the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it'll be hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rules in firestore.
I mean, set the read and write rules to anyone, simply change the condition in fire store rules.

Comment: Yes that's a temporary fix but i have authentication enabled. Even though the user is logged in i can't write

Answer (score 0):

The default rules on the Firestore database are: 
allow read, write: if false; which means you can't read or write to it.  Change it to: allow read, write: if request.auth != null;